# UiPicker Action iPhone Help

Tags: ios4

could any one help me.in the problem below.
I have a UI Picker and i want to get some action to be done while selecting a item fro it how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //write your action here.    
}
```